# setOnClickListener android studio

Tags: java, android

I´m learning Java in android studio with an online material

But i got stucked at this simple program

Android Studio says that there is error in this code, but i can not see them, here is the code:

```
package com.acmegames.listadecontatos;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.app.*;


public class ListaContatosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lista_contatos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_contatos);

        lista_contatos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_contatos);

        lista_contatos.setOnClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String nome = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo =  new AlertDialog.Builder(ListaContatosActivity.this);
                dialogo.setTitle("Contato");
                dialogo.setMessage("Contato selecionado: " + nome);
                dialogo.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
                dialogo.show();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `setOnClickListener` to `setOnItemClickListener` for list view

Answer (score 0):

Replace it like this you r using on click in on item click thats the error

```
lista_contatos.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String nome = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo =  new AlertDialog.Builder(ListaContatosActivity.this);
            dialogo.setTitle("Contato");
            dialogo.setMessage("Contato selecionado: " + nome);
            dialogo.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
            dialogo.show();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

just copy and paste below code

```
package com.acmegames.listadecontatos;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.app.*;


public class ListaContatosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lista_contatos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_contatos);

        lista_contatos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_contatos);

        lista_contatos.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String nome = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo =  new AlertDialog.Builder(ListaContatosActivity.this);
                dialogo.setTitle("Contato");
                dialogo.setMessage("Contato selecionado: " + nome);
                dialogo.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
                dialogo.show();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

you should use setOnItemClickListener instead of SetOnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

If you use setOnclicklistener, u should not create new onItemClickListener. And for listview use setOnItemListener. Or if you customize your adapter, you can use Onclicklistener for the view inside that adapter.